# is there a way to put a blank entry in place of a node value for the particular classes that don't contain that node with Scrapy and Python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using python and scrapy to pull information from a database of companies online. Each company's information is completely contained in a parent node but not every company has a child node containing its website, some only have the company name. This means when i pull the data with xpath i'm getting 20 company names but only 18 web addresses (per page) which means when i zip up the lists and export i'm only getting the first 18 companies and the websites don't match. is there a way to insert a blank entry into the website list for the companies that don't have the website information node as one of the child nodes.

Thank you

```html
<div class="company">
  <p class="website">
      www.company.co.uk</p>
   ...
</div>
<div class="company">
...
</div>
```

from the above, when i run

```html
xpath('//div[@class="company"]/p/text()')
```

ideally i'd get `['www.company.co.uk','']` with a blank entry for the second company node since they don't have a p node for the website. when i run xpath i'm getting a longer list of company names than websites so the lists don't match when i zip them together

Comment: Code snippet please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls, attach some code so people could get better understanding of you problem...

Overall, you should follow next pattern:

```
companies = response.xpath('//...some xpath here')
for company in companies:
    item = {}
    item['title'] = company.xpath('./...some title xpath here relative to company node').extract_first()
    item['website'] = company.xpath('./...some website xpath').extract_first()
    yield item
```